# Do HornetQ clusters use JBoss clustering when embedded?

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, wildfly

I'll be using HornetQ 2.3.12 embedded in JBoss EAP 6.2 and need to have a few clustered queues.

Do I need to set up a JBoss cluster in order to have JMS clusters powered by HornetQ or HornetQ is independent? Based on the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/clusters.html), I think it's the latter because the HornetQ clustering is part of HornetQ and can exist without JBoss.

The nodes are connected with a [core bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/core-bridges.html) so the application deployed in each node will do a local JNDI lookup for the queue name, without the need to have clustered JNDI. Another reason that removes the need for the JBoss cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HornetQ's clustering is totally independent of JBoss. You don't need to start any clustered thing on JBoss in order to start HornetQ's clustering.

Having said that most of the EAP examples on clustering come under JBoss Clustering tree. but that was just a choice to not confuse documentation. HornetQ is totally independent of JBoss on these terms